# Execute a function periodically every 10ms on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am currently working on a program that must do some work regularly. At the moment I using the following construction:

```
int main(int argn, char** argv) {
    for(;;) {
        //Do work - the programm spends 5-8ms here

        nanosleep(...); //Sleep 10ms
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: One loop execution should always last 10ms. Because of the high amount of time spend in the working part of the loop I can't sleep simply sleep for 10ms...

A solution might be measuring the time spend on work with `clock_gettime()` and adjust the `nanosleep()` accordingly. But I am not happy with this solution, because it's very easy to place code outside the area that's measured...

I have searched the internet for alternatives, I found the three calls:

- timer_create
- getitimer
- alarm
- timerfd_create

It's okay if the solution is not portable to Windows or other operating systems.

But I am not sure which solutions fits best to my problem. Any advice or suggestions? What are the pros and cons with the 4 alternatives I mentioned?

**EDIT:** There is also another problem with this solution: If i get the documentation right, the `nanosleep` syscall put the process into sleep for at least 10ms, but it can take longer if the system is under load... Is there any way to optimize that?

**EDIT2:** For your information: In the do work part a network request is made to a another device on the network (a microcontroller or a PLC that is able to answer the request in time). The result is being processed and send back to the device. I know Linux is not a realtime OS and not optimal for this kind of task... It's no problem if the solution is not perfect realtime, but it would be nice to get as much realtime as possible.

Comment: Why is this tagged both C and C++? Without knowing what language you are using, how can we give you example code?

Comment: The program (in the Do work comment) is written in C++ but I think the problem can only be solved using a C system call...

Comment: C++ has the same system calls as C.

Comment: I know, but not everybody here who is able to solve this problem subscribed to the c++ tag in stackoverflow. And it's also possible to solve this task with only using C-Code...

Comment: Right, but we have to know which language you want a solution for. With both tags, there's no way to know. It can be solved using `std::chrono`, for example. You should only use two language tags if your question relates to the differences or similarities in the two languages. Otherwise, it just creates confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`clock_nanosleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html) which lets you request to sleep until a given absolute time (`TIMER_ABSTIME` flag) rather than taking a duration. Then you can simply increment the destination absolute time by 10ms on every iteration.

Using `clock_nanosleep` also allows you (if you want) to use the monotonic clock option and avoid having to deal with the possibility of the user/admin resetting the system clock while your program is running.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I wasn't aware of `clock_nanosleep`. I will check this solution in the next days :-) Can you also provide some information about the accuracy of this method (see edited question)?

Comment: @flammi88: If you want to rigorously avoid oversleeping due to load from other threads/processes, you need to have your thread run with an appropriate realtime priority, which normally requires root permissions to set. However unless you expect terrible load, you'll probably be fine. Why not conduct some simple tests under load to see how it behaves?

Comment: This solution works best for me. Btw. the realtime performance on my system is quite well if i reset the scheduler with `sched_setscheduler` to SCHED_FIFO (requires root priviledges, but that's ok for me).

Answer (score 1):

Check the time right before the call to `nanosleep` and compute how long to sleep right there. There will be no need to measure any code. Just note the time you return from `nanosleep` and calculate how much more time you need to sleep.

Comment: But is that the preferred way of doing that? I could imagine that the scheduler of the operating system might be able to do some optimizations if you solve this with signals. For example the scheduler could wake up the program more precisely... Do you know how accurate this solution is?

Comment: @flammi88 Accuracy is going to suck for all these methods for a variety of reasons. Linux isn't a real-time OS. There's probably a much better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do, but you didn't tell us what you're trying to do, just how you planned to accomplish it.

Comment: I edited the question and added some more information about that what i am planning to do.

Answer (score 1):

Signal Handling is the most preferred way to do it .I prefer [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) as it is posix function conforming to POSIX.1-2001.  Microsoft also provides [help for writing POSIX Standard Code](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463220.aspx#EYAA).