# sleep_until in embedded_linux in multi-threaded environment (embedded Linux)

Tags: timer, embedded, embedded-linux

I have a pseudo RT system that is running multiple threads. I want each thread to execute at specific frequency (period interval). I have been using usleep(time_until_reschedule). The problem is that time_until_reschedule could be computed, then a higher priority thread could preempt this thread, and I would like to avoid such behavior.

I would like to implement something that acts like "sleep_until". I am thinking of using hrtimers (built in my kernel) with SIGEV_THREAD_ID to notify each thread while the thread calls sigwait().

Is this a sensible way of implementing a sort of sleep_until() or is there a better way under Linux please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what your threads need to do, but you could use a combination of `clock_nanosleep` and [Earliest Deadline First scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling). You could sleep without computing the sleep duration, and if you are scare that your thread is not going to be waken up because other threads are CPU hogs, than EDF may be a solution for you.

For clock_nanosleep check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165817/795910).
For the EDF scheduler, check this [article](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2015/25/Optimizing-utilization-with-the-EDF-scheduler).

Comment: Thanks, this looks a good solution to my problem! I didn't know about clock_nanosleep or the EDF, Thanks a lot!